# In $Ax = b$, can $x$ be a polynomial of arbitrary degree(Python)?

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, python

I am working on an algorithm to solve problems of the form $Ax = b$. In this problem, I expect $x$ to be a polynomial(of arbitrary degree greater than 1, i.e., nonlinear). I am new to Python and finiding it difficult to implement this condition in Python. Any suggestion(s) or reference(s) will be highly appreciated.

$A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix while $b$ is an $m \times 1$ vector. The polynomial $x$ is of arbitrary order $n$

Comment: A polynomial in what? The vector index $n$? Some auxiliary parameter $t$?

Comment: of vector index n, please

Comment: What are $A$ and $b$?

Comment: $A$ is a matrix in $m$ by $n$, $b$ is a $n$ by $1$

Comment: @MaliMail Don't you mean that $x$ is $n\times1$ while $b$ is $m\times1$?

Comment: Is this a linear transformation between polynomials that you're trying to realize as a matrix-vector product where the basis vectors are shorthand for $1$, $x$, $x^2$, etc?

Comment: @Cameron Williams This is the basic idea I am looking at with the basis vectors as $1, x, x^2,...$

Comment: So $x$ is actually a polynomial in some auxiliary parameter $t$ (or if you prefer the solution is $p$ and the parameter is $x$), and so is $b$. In that case once you express everything in some particular polynomial basis, everything is the same as in the case for vectors.

Comment: Thank you, Ian. I am just curious how to plot my polynomial from here...am I missing something?

Comment: Once you've solved the equation, you have the coefficients (in whatever basis you picked) which you can use to evaluate the polynomial.